# SQL convert plus where

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this code

```
Dim datetofind As Date
datetofind = Calendar1.SelectedDate
AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE ([Date] = '" & datetofind & "') "
```

The date field stores the value as `dd/mm/yyyy 0.00.00` and there is no way to change it.
How to apply the SQL convert function so that `datetofind` would be comparable to `Date`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Access database and AccessDataSource command

Comment: Access default date structure is mm/dd/yyyy. Why do you say it is saved as dd/mm/yyyy? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```sql
"SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE ([Date] = #" & datetofind & "#) "
```

Comment: # delimiter instead of apostrophe is correct for date/time fields; however, since this appears to be a non-U.S. database, possible that will not resolve issue with international date structure.

Comment: Thanks!! It works but I had to change datetofind = Calendar1.SelectedDate to datetofind = Calendar1.SelectedDate. Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy"). Thank you very much.